# Scraping a sliding table os Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get data from a sliding table on a website (like those stockmarket prices on some websites).

I'm using this line:

```
elem=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div/article/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/aside/div/div/div/ul/li')
```

It seems to get all the elements to the list just fine.
But once I use any method on the list, let's say:

```
for i in elem:
    print(i.text)
```

It actually just return the values visible at that very moment.

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in most cases try in the following order:

**getText()** if it doesn't work use **getAttribute('textContent')** if that too doesn't work use **getAttribute('value')**

getAttribute('value') works only if there is an attribute called value in your element (like id, name etc)

So in most cases, if getText doesn't work use **.getAttribute('textContent')**
Use:

```
 i.get_attribute("textContent")
```

Because getText or text() actually uses innerText ,and will not detect text from hidden elements .

> Don't get confused by the differences between Node.textContent and
> HTMLElement.innerText. Although the names seem similar, there are
> important differences:
>
> textContent gets the content of all elements, including  and
> elements. In contrast, innerText only shows “human-readable” elements.
>
> textContent returns every element in the node. In contrast, innerText
> is aware of styling and won’t return the text of “hidden” elements.
>
> Moreover, since innerText takes CSS styles into account, reading the
> value of innerText triggers a reflow to ensure up-to-date computed
> styles. (Reflows can be computationally expensive, and thus should be
> avoided when possible.)
>
> Unlike textContent, altering innerText in Internet Explorer (version
> 11 and below) removes child nodes from the element and permanently
> destroys all descendant text nodes. It is impossible to insert the
> nodes again into any other element or the same element after
> doing so

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
for i in elem:
    print(i.get_attribute('textContent'))
```

to get text from hidden elements as well